# Change directory on remote server with zsh

Tags: ssh, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I usually ssh into my aws account then immediately change directory to my working directory.

I am now using an alias in my .zshrc file for the ssh command. However , ideally, I'd like to ssh in then change directories automatically with my alias command. Cant figure out the cd part on the remote server. My alias looks something like this now:

`alias aws="ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykeypair.pem ubuntu@11.11.111.11"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the preferred way would be creating `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` file on your remote host or appending to the end just:

```
cd your/working/directory/
```

Just tested and works fine for me

Other way would be changing your alias to something like:

```
alias aws="ssh -tt -i ~/.ssh/mykeypair.pem ubuntu@11.11.111.11 'cd your/working/directory/; bash'"
```

Additionally you can change `bash` for `zsh` if you want to use `zsh` as your shell on remote host.

Comment: Using the second option, i get a "quote>" at the command line.  Not sure why . What does that mean?  For the first option, where do you place the .zshrc file?  Do i need to install zsh or just the file?    When you say " ... or appending to the end" what do you mean?

Comment: if you use zsh on remote system, it is there installed and in your home directory, there is file `.zshrc`. If not, you are using some different shell on remote machine and depending on it there is similar file, for example bash has `.bashrc`. Also you would need to change the shell name in the second command to `bash` for example.

Comment: @user2022284 you get the "quote>" prompt because the closing `'` was missing after `zsh` just before the closing `"`. It is fixed now.

Comment: I am getting a  `bash: zsh: command not found` after applying the change @Adaephon suggested.

Comment: So go on with bash on remote host, if you don't have zsh there: `alias aws="ssh -tt -i ~/.ssh/mykeypair.pem ubuntu@11.11.111.11 'cd your/working/directory/; bash"`

Comment: Yay! It works!. Thanks. Now I am almost tempted to install zsh on the remote server. What are the downsides of doing that? And is the process the same as installing on my local machine? This is an AWS ubuntu instance. btw, I am using oh-my-zsh